# How to avoid "resource too old" when retrying a watch with kubernetes python client?

Tags: python, kubernetes

The following code will throw an `ApiException 410 resource too old` on the second `watch.stream()`:

```
# python3 -m venv venv
# source venv/bin/activate
# pip install 'kubernetes==23.3.0'

from kubernetes import client,config,watch

config.load_kube_config(context='my-eks-context')

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
watcher = watch.Watch()


namespace = 'kube-system'
last_resource_version=0

# this watch will timeout in 5s to have a fast way to simulate a watch that need to be retried 
for i in  watcher.stream(v1.list_namespaced_pod, namespace, resource_version=last_resource_version, timeout_seconds=5):
   print(i['object'].metadata.resource_version)
   last_resource_version = i['object'].metadata.resource_version


# we retry the watch starting from the last resource version known
# but this will raise a kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (410)
# Reason: Expired: too old resource version: 379140622 (380367990)
for i in  watcher.stream(v1.list_namespaced_pod, namespace, resource_version=last_resource_version, timeout_seconds=5):
    print('second loop', i['object'].metadata.resource_version)
    last_resource_version = i['object'].metadata.resource_version
```

The [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes) states that:

> If a client watch is disconnected then that client can start a new watch from the last returned resourceVersion

which is what I intended in the above code, which always gives the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>

  File "/Users/rubelagu/git/python-kubernetes-client/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 182, in stream
    raise client.rest.ApiException(
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (410)
Reason: Expired: too old resource version: 379164133 (380432814)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in the initial response to the watch (from an EKS cluster 1.21) the events can be returned in any order.

I did two subsequent watches two seconds apart and they contain the same 30 events in completely different ordering.

So it's not guaranteed that the last resource version that you see is actually the actual last and it's not guaranteed that you can resume from that `resourceVersion`/`resource_version`. Also you are not allowed to sort/collate those events by `resourceVersion`, since the [kubernetes documentation for Resource Version Semantics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#resource-versions) explicity says:

> Resource versions must be treated as **opaque** [...] You **must not** assume resource versions are **numeric or collatable**.

You must account for that by catching the `resource too old exception` and retrying without specifying a resource version, see below for an example:

```
from kubernetes import client,config,watch
from kubernetes.client.exceptions import ApiException

config.load_kube_config(context='eks-prod')

v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
# v1 = config.new_client_from_config(context="eks-prod").CoreV1Api()
watcher = watch.Watch()


namespace = 'my-namespace'


def list_pods(resource_version=None):
   print('start watch from resource version: ', str(resource_version))
   try: 
      for i in  watcher.stream(v1.list_namespaced_pod, namespace, resource_version=resource_version, timeout_seconds=2):
         print(i['object'].metadata.resource_version)
         last_resource_version = i['object'].metadata.resource_version
   except ApiException as e: 
      if e.status == 410: # Resource too old
         return list_pods(resource_version=None)
      else:
         raise

   return last_resource_version

last_resource_version = list_pods()

print('last_resource_version', last_resource_version)

list_pods(last_resource_version)
```